Why is my one-thread multithreaded Python code faster than a single-threaded solution, and why does performance degrade with more threads?
I'm working on a Python script to calculate the sum of a large list of random integers. Here's the code for the single-threaded version:
import time
import random

large_list = [random.randint(-100, 100) for _ in range(200000000)]
start_time = time.time()
total = 0
for n in large_list:
    total += n

print(total)
print(time.time() - start_time)

This outputs:
-1153397 # total sum
9.442509889602661 # time taken

I then tried to parallelize this using multithreading with the following code:
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

start_time = time.time()
_num_threads = 10
total = 0

del chunks

def partial_sum(chunk):
    total = 0
    for n in chunk:
        total += n
    return total

chunk_size = len(large_list) // _num_threads

chunks = [large_list[i * chunk_size: (i + 1) * chunk_size] for i in range(_num_threads)]

if len(large_list) % _num_threads != 0:
    chunks.append(large_list[_num_threads * chunk_size:])

# Calculate the partial sums in parallel
with ThreadPool(processes=_num_threads) as pool:
    partial_sums = pool.map(partial_sum, chunks)

total_sum = sum(partial_sums)

print(total_sum)
print(time.time() - start_time)

Running it with 10 threads on a 12-core CPU, I get:
-1153397  # total sum (expected to be around zero)
8.065398454666138  # time taken

However, running it with just one thread gives:
-1153397  # total sum (same as before)
5.773534536361694  # time taken

My questions:

Why is the one thread version of the multi-threaded code much faster than the single-thread approach?

Why does the performance degrade when I increase the number of threads to 10, even though my CPU has 12 cores?


I expected the multi-threaded code to be faster, or at least not slower when using more threads. What could be causing this behavior?
I tried running the code above several times, and I got consistent results to the ones presented. However , I was expecting the one threaded version of the multi-thread code to be as fast (or even slower due to overhead) as the single-thread implementation, and I expected the 10-threaded version to be much faster than the other two approaches.

You're doing CPU-bound work, so you're limited by the GIL. It's being sequentially executed; just across multiple threads.

Threads run concurrently, not in parallel. The time you spend setting up and switching between multiple threads is time you could have spent adding numbers.

Also, if you are performing all the timings in one process, you may be seeing cache effects that could artificially speed up later tests.

Please provide a [mcve]. The parallelized code you show will not run, either as a standalone program or as a block added to the nonparallelized script, due to chunks being deleted before it is ever defined. This throws into doubt what you are actually executing and timing.

The single-threaded version is slow because it repeatedly rewrites global variables. You should use partial_sum(large_list) for a fair comparison.

Thanks for all your comments. @chepner I added the del chunks line to make sure chunks are not cached between executions. For the first execution, I delete this line of code.

@HéctorBalsellsRoure del chunks is completely pointless
